# OOo Display bullet points one at a time

Tags: openoffice, presentations, openoffice-impress

How can I set up slides in my Open Office presentation to display bullet points one at a time? In this case I want to apply this to all bullet points in all slides but I don't mind adding it one text box at a time as it's a small presentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found answer:

1. Add custom animation
2. Go to `Effect Options`
3. Under `Text Animation` set `Group text` to `By 1st level paragraphs`

Answer found on Ubuntu forums. Couldn't find anything up-to-date on the OOo support site.